# cannot make image_view from source on gumstix Overo

Tags: ros, opencv, libopencv, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to make image_view(fuerte version) from source on gumstix Overo(running Linaro).

But I got the following error:

```
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                     
[ rosmake ] All 27 linesv_bridge: 116.7 sec ]         [ 1 Active 4/17 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  make: Warning: File `/root/ros_core_ws/install/share/mk/buildtest.mk' has modification time 4.1e+08 s in the future
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/root/ros_core_ws/install/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package cv_bridge
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  Failed to invoke /root/ros_core_ws/install/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only cv_bridge
  [rospack] Warning: ignoring duplicate cpp tag in export block
  Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
```

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found

```
  CMake Error at /root/ros_core_ws/install/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):


    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'cv_bridge'.
    Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
    broken dependency!

  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /root/ros_core_ws/install/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:227 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

It seems the third party package opencv2 haven't been installed. I tried install it by "rosdep install image_view", but I got following error:

```
root@linaro-alip:~# rosdep install image_view
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
image_view: Missing resource smclib
ROS path [0]=/root/ros_core_ws/install/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/root/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/root/ros_core_ws/install/share
ROS path [3]=/root/ros_core_ws/install/stacks
```

Do I need to install smclib by source?

Also, I have downloaded and make the [opencv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/?source=directory), can I simply make install it and then can rosmake find 'opencv'?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56384/cannot-make-image_view-from-source-on-gumstix-overo/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

please refer to http://answers.ros.org/question/38126/rosmake-error-costmap_2d-depends-on-non-existent-package-pcl/

---

Originally posted by [Praseen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5042/praseen/) with karma: 28 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0